# Is the degree of an irreducible inseparable polynomial always a p-power?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

Consider a field $K$ of characteristic $p>0$. Let $f$ be an irreducible, inseparable polynomial in $K[Y]$. I'm wondering if the degree of $f$ has to be a power of $p$.

For instance, the standard example is $f=Y-X^p\in \mathbb{F}_p(X)[Y]$ and it factors as $f=(\sqrt[p]{Y}-X)^p$. All examples that I can find are in essentially coming from this one. I can't thing about anything else.

In particular I'm asking my self if it is possible that:
if $f$ is an inseparable irreducible polynomial in $K[Y]$, f factors in $L=K[Y]/f$ as
$$(*)\;\;\;\;\;f=g\cdot\prod_{i=1}^d(Y-\alpha_i),$$
with the $\alpha_i\in L$ pairwise distinct and $g$ irreducible in $L[Y]$ and inseparable over $L$.

I don't think so, but I can't see it properly. Also I can't find a precise statement in the literature.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^{pq}-t$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126730/inseparable-irreducible-polynomials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to a multiplicative constant $c\in K^*$, an irreducible polynomial $f=\sum_{i=0}^n c_i X^i\in K[X]$ is the minimal polynomial $f_K^\alpha$ of some $\alpha\in \overline{K}$. Since we must have $f'=0$ in $K[X]$, we see by using the formal derivative that $f=\sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^{ip}$.

Hence $\deg f$ is always a multiple of $p$.